# AngularFire - Remove Single Item

Tags: angularjs, pug, firebase, angularfire

Here is the relevant code in my view:

```
p(ng-repeat="t in todos")
input(
    type="checkbox",
    ng-model="t.done",
    ng-click="clearItem($event)"
    )
{{t.text}} done? {{t.done}}
```

When the checkbox is clicked, I want the appropriate object in the `todos` array to be removed from the database.

My `clearItem` function is as follows:

```
$scope.clearItem = function(event) {
        todoRef.remove($scope.t);
    }
```

However, this removes all the entries in my database. I want it to remove only the specific object in question. Is there anyway for me to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

When looping using `ng-repeat`, use `(id, t) in todos`. This allows you to send `id` as the parameter to the `ng-click` function, and `$scope.todos.$remove(id)` works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

To provide a more complete example for anyone else that lands here, according to [Firebase's documentation for AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html) this would be the preferred way, and I believe the easiest way to remove an object:

```
// Create an app. Synch a Firebase array inside a controller
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["firebase"]);

// inject $firebaseArray 
myApp.controller("TodoCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {

  // bind $scope.todos to Firebase database
  $scope.todos = $firebaseArray(myFirebaseRef.child("todo"));

  // create a destroy function
  $scope.removeTodo = function(todo) {
    $scope.todos.$remove(todo); 
  };
}]);
```

In your view, you could do something like below. Note that you could bind the removeTodo function to a checkbox as the question specifies, or a regular old `<a href>` element:

```
// In your view
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
      {{ todo.text }} : <a href ng-click="removeTodo(todo)">X</a>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to have `$scope.clearItem()` take the object `t` as an argument, instead of `$event`.

HTML - `<p ng-repeat="t in todos"><input... ng-click="clearItem(t)">`

JS - `$scope.clearItem = function(obj) {todoRef.$remove(obj)};`

Answer (score 1):

The only way I'm able to remove the item is using a loop on the array we get from firebase.

```
var ref= new Firebase('https://Yourapp.firebaseio.com/YourObjectName');
var arr_ref=$firebaseArray(ref);
    for(var i=0;i<arr_ref.length;i++){
        if(key==arr_ref[i].$id){
            console.log(arr_ref[i]);
            arr_ref.$remove(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: slfan Check this out now

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove the object would be

```
scope.clearItem = function(event) {
  todoRef.$loaded().then(function(){
   todoRef.$remove($scope.t)
 });
```

The asynchronous nature of the beast has gotten me a few times.